# Perl Ошибка при запросе через прокси к https сайту. AnyEvent

Tags: perl

Все привет, при запросе через прокси, который поддерживает https к https сайту. Приходит ошибка 
'Reason' => 'ssl23_get_server_hello: unknown protocol',
'Status' => 596,

Использую библиотеку AnyEvent, подозреваю, что проблема с запросом connect, но никак не получается решить, буду очень признателен за подсказку.

```
use strict;
use utf8;
use Data::Dumper;

use AnyEvent::HTTP;
use MIME::Base64;
use AnyEvent::Connector;


my $cookies = {};
my $done = AnyEvent->condvar;

my $request_watcher = http_request(
    get => 'https://randomup.ru',
    (
        keepalive  => 1,
        persistent => 1,
        recurse    => 0,
        cookie_jar => $cookies,
        timeout    => 10,
        headers    => {
            'user-agent'      => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3445.2 Safari/537.36',
            'accept-encoding' => 'gzip',
            'Accept-Language'=> 'en-us,en;q=0.5',
            'Accept-Charset'=> 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
            'Proxy-Authorization' => 'Basic ' . encode_base64('XXX' . ':' . 'XXX'),
        },
    ),
    on_header => sub {
        print STDERR Dumper @_;

        return 1;
    },
    proxy => ['XX.XX.XX.XX', 8000, 'http'],
    sub {
        print STDERR Dumper @_;
        #$done->send;

    }
);
$done->recv();
```

Подозреваю, что нужен еще метод tcp_connect, но не понимаю, как его еще нужно настроить.

Comment: Через LWP::UserAgent все работает хорошо.

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->proxy('https', 'http://XXX:XXX@XXXX:8000');
# $ua->proxy(['https'], 'https://proxy:8080'); # Fails
# $ua->env_proxy; # This also fails.

my $response = $ua->get('https://randomup.ru');

if ($response->is_success) {
    print $response->decoded_content;  # or whatever
}
else {
    die $response->status_line;
}

Comment: Я сделал copy/paste, запустил, и получил такой ризалт: https://imgur.com/a/aOs9fml - Скажите, скрипт должен работать именно так? Использовал ``perl 5.20.2`` + ``Debian``.

Comment: Судя по всему, у вас ошибка где-то в портах/протоколах! Не будет работать, к примеру, https://vk.com:80, однако http://vk.com:80 - работает.